# MassTransit & Amazon SQS - EventType being created as a queue

Tags: .net-core, amazon-sqs, masstransit

I have just migrated from RabbitMq to Amazon SQS.

One thing that's happening which I dont want is the Message Type is being created as queue when I use docker & IHostedService startup:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMassTransit(x =>
        {
            x.AddConsumer<EmailSentConsumer>();

            x.AddBus(provider => Bus.Factory.CreateUsingAmazonSqs(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.Host("eu-west-2", h =>
                {
                    h.AccessKey("********");
                    h.SecretKey("********");
                });

                cfg.ReceiveEndpoint("logging_example_queue", e =>
                {
                    //e.ConfigureConsumer<EmailSentConsumer>(provider);
                    //e.ConfigureConsumer<EmailReceivedConsumer>(provider);
                });

                cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(provider);
            }));
        });

        services.AddSingleton<IHostedService, BusService>();

        services.AddMassTransitHostedService();
    }
```

---

```
public class EmailSentConsumer : IConsumer<EmailSent>
```

EmailSent is being set up as a queue, when I just want this service listening for that event type in the logging_example_queue.

When I set this up via a simple console app, and have the Consumers within the configure endpoint

```
            cfg.ReceiveEndpoint("logging_queue", e =>
            {
                e.Consumer<ConsumerTo>();
                e.Consumer<AnotherConsumer>();
            });
```

This works fine, any suggestions?

**EDIT**

So, I have tried Chris answer, and this doesn't create the queue as suggested, but I do need the topic. I want this as an example:

Topic EmailSent:
Queue: Logging
Queue: EmailListener

Here are the screenshots from AWS:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
            cfg.ReceiveEndpoint("logging_example_queue", e =>
            {
                //e.ConfigureConsumer<EmailSentConsumer>(provider);
                //e.ConfigureConsumer<EmailReceivedConsumer>(provider);
            });

            cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(provider);
```

This is the issue, fixed this by changing the configureendpoints, as below:

```
                cfg.ReceiveEndpoint("logging_example_queue", e =>
                {
                    e.ConfigureConsumers(provider);
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

`EmailSent` should be created as a topic in SNS, but not a queue.

If you do not want the topics to be created, add:

```
ConfigureConsumeTopology = false;
```

to the receive endpoint configuration. Also, don’t call `Publish` as that would also create the topic.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It does create the topic, but it definitely creates a queue too, updating my question with the screenshots now.